# Clarification on database architecture question

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a quiz for this internship and one question is worded strangely. I'm hoping that one of you could help me find clarification.

Context: I've just created a flat-file table (database), and added 4 columns (UserId,firstname,lastname,email). I filled each column with 15 rows of made-up data.

The question states "Query all rows in the firstname column that start with the letter B and ordered by the lastname column in descending order."

I'm not sure what they're asking for, does this make sense to you?

Comment: Yeah. Look at all the records one by one and only goose the records/rows where first name starts with B (where firstname like ‘B%’. Once you have the filtered rows, arrange the rows so that last name is sorted z->a (order by lastname desc)

Comment: What does "flat-file table (database)" mean - just a simple text file? (That's what [Wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat-file_database) looks like.) Were you expected to import this into SQL Server? Is there any mention of e.g. gnu awk or grep in your instructions i.e. might they expect you to extract data from the file directly? Or e.g. write some code in C++ or C# to read the file and extract and sort the data? What's the architecture angle here?

Comment: That is poorly worded! Perhaps better phrasing would be "Return (or retrieve or select?) all rows that have a firstname that starts with B and sort those rows by lastname in descending order." Improvement?

Answer (score 3):

The question is asking you to query the table, selecting the firstname column and all data that starts with the letter 'B'. And then ordered by the lastname. It's a fairly basic query:

```
SELECT t.firstname
FROM tablename t
WHERE t.firstname like 'B%'
ORDER BY t.lastname DESC;
```

EDIT: I did forget the DESC;

Answer (score 2):

The query consists in retrieving first names and last names of rows where the firstname starts with the letter B, and then to order the resulting set using the lastname field in descending order.

The query in sql would be like:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE 'B%' ORDER BY lastname DESC;
```